# SSH into server on network - and then access a web interface (ip only, no port)

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I'm trying to access the web interface of my NAS externally.

What I tried:

In putty - make an ssh tunnel on 80, then I fill in the IP of the web interface, on port 80 aswell (I think this part is wrong, since locally I dont use a port, just an internal ip adress).

Then I connect to the server, which works. but when I go to localhost:80 on the external machine, I get this:
webpage is not available - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Am I setting it up right?

Comment: try using `http://127.0.0.1:80`, or whatever local port your tunnel originates from, in your browser. When you tunnel, you are creating a connection between a local port and a remote port. when you want a client application to use the tunnel, you point it to the local port, not the remote one. the tunnel will take the local port and send all traffic addressed to it to the remote port and its application. for instance if you created a tunnel between local 8080 and remote 80, any traffic on `localhost:8080` will be forwarded to `www.remotehost.com:80`.

Comment: I know that - but I don't want to forward a port to here. Just an IP adress. when im on my pc at home - i fill in the adress bar x.x.x.x for my device, not x.x.x.x:xx

Comment: Okay let me try to clarify it. When I'm at home I can connect to my nas at lets say 192.168.192.51. I then get into the web interface, where i can manage my nas. 
I have a linux server, where i can ssh into from work. on 192.168.192.49.
so at work - i want to connect to the linux server (192.168.192.49) and then connect to the web interface at 192.168.192.51.

the 192.168.192.49 is accessible externally, the 192.168.192.51 is not.

Comment: @Spherehunter, you state that you don't put in a port number when you are on your PC at home, just the IP address. If you don't specify the port number in a web browser, for HTTP the browser automatically assumes port 80 or port 443 for HTTPS. So you don't have to specify it, but your browser certainly has to connect to the correct port for the web port of the NAS for you to access its web interface. So you need to forward port 80 through PuTTY, since that is the default HTTP port.

Comment: And that is what i did, but it wont connect.

Comment: ahh, ok you want to tunnel THROUGH the ssh server, not to it. that will require a proxy server on both ends I believe. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Yes - I am connecting to that. And no - i create the tunnel to the Linux box, the nas is the device i need to access. And i want to access that via the linux box. Yes THOUGH! :D

Comment: I understand. that is not usually how it works, but I believe it can be done, with the appropriate proxy servers. One way to do it would be to install sshd on the nas, then ssh into the linux server on 22, and create a tunnel between the server:80 and the nas:80. Then on your work system, create the tunnel from localhost:80 to server:80. then you point your browser to `http://127.0.0.1`. traffic entering localhost:80 will be directed to server:80, which will then forward it to nas:80.

Comment: Ah yeah - that requires me to enable SSH on the NAS, which i have to do from the web interface..so that's not working from this end.
Seems i will have to do that when i get home. But thanks, i will try that when i have the time to enable ssh :)!

Comment: @Frank Thomas, PuTTY supports forwarding ports to other addresses than the SSH server to which PuTTY is logging in, so it isn't necessary to install SSH server on the NAS nor use a proxy server. If the NAS is on the same LAN as the Linux server, Spherehunter should be able to port forward to the NAS IP address by configuring PuTTY appropriately.

Comment: That is correct, but you still need proxies. you can enable a socks proxy in PuTTY (the port forward feature), but this also requires that you configure your browser to use a proxy server that directs packets into the local end of the tunnel, (localhost:80 or whatever) in order to access the remote network via the socks proxy putty provides. additionally you have to be using protocols that play nicely with Socksv5, and use client apps that support proxy configuration to get your traffic into the tunnel in the first place. http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/

Comment: @Frank Thomas, yes he could use a SOCKS proxy. That would be the best technique should he need general access to any web server via the Linux box that is the SSH server. But if he only needs access to the web interface on the NAS device, he can simply forward port 80 to its IP address. No proxy is needed. E.g., he could forward port 8080 to port 80 at the IP address for the NAS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should SSH into the Linux box as you are now, but instead of port forwarding to 127.0.0.1:80 or localhost:80, you need to port forward the connection to the IP address of the NAS. If the NAS device is at 192.168.192.51, then the port forwarding configuration in PuTTY needs to be to 192.168.192.51:80, i.e., port 80 for the NAS IP address, e.g., see [Port forwarding to another device with PuTTY](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/network/ssh/putty/forward-port80.php).

Alternatively, you could use the [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy technique suggested by Frank Thomas in his comment. That is definitely a better solution should you wish to access web servers other than just the one running on the NAS device through the SSH server. For specific steps to set up a SOCKS proxy using PuTTY, see [Using PuTTY to set up a SOCKS Proxy Connection](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/putty/). To use that technique, you also need to configure your browser to route connections through the SOCKS proxy you created with PuTTY and then reconfigure the browser to no longer use the SOCKS proxy when you no longer want to route web traffic through the SSH server. But that is relatively simple to do. Steps to configure some browsers on Windows to use a SOCKS proxy are provided from the links below:

[Chrome](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2015/01/11#chrome-windows)

[Internet Explorer 6](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/ie6-sshsocks-proxy.php)

[Internet Explorer 10](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/ie10-socks-proxy.php)

You can find the steps for other browsers by searching on the browser name and "socks proxy configuration".

Once you have the browser configured to use the SOCKS proxy, put the IP address of the NAS device in your web browser, not 127.0.0.1 or localhost., e.g., http://192.168.192.51. You don't need to add the default port number of 80 in this case to access the web interface on the NAS device.

Comment: Okay - this is what i fill in at PuTTy:
Hostname: My external IP.
Port: 22

SSH->Tunnels:
source port:8888
Destination:192.168.192.51:80 (or :443, both wont work)

i leave the radio buttons on local, and auto.

Then i connect - log in with my credentials.

then i go to google chrome, and type localhost:8888

then i get:

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @Spherehunter, I added a link in my answer to a page with some screenshots of what the PuTTY configuration should look like. From what you wrote in your comment, though, I don't immediately see any error in your settings. Is the NAS device on the same LAN as the Linux SSH server with no firewalls in between? Do you know if the NAS device permits connectivity to its web interface from any IP address on the LAN or do you have it configured to permit access from only 1 IP address? If you were sitting at the Linux box could you access the NAS web interface from it?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like the screenshots. I can access it with the linux box at home, and i can access it from a windows pc. So it should not be restricted to 1 ip adress. Same LAN yeah, both wired connections and no firewalls in between there.

Comment: At the moment I don't see why that isn't working for you. After I realized I had written instructions a couple of months ago for how to  use PuTTY to create a SOCKS proxy, I updated my answer again so you might also try the technique suggested by Frank Thomas. If you wish to try that approach, go to [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com) before configuring the browser to use a SOCKS proxy and then again afterwards. After configuring the browser, the site should show the IP address associated with the Linux server. Then try accessing the NAS device again.